# Printing Phone Number (String) to excel using Apache POI show up as scientific notation (4.165551234E9)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openxml

How can I change the Cell so that it appears as a 'general' type instead of 'scientific'

Here's the line that causes issues, `getPhoneNumber()` returns a String

```
row.createCell(4).setCellValue(c.getPhoneNumber());
```

Phone numbers (strings) show up as 4.165551234E9, the data is there but in the wrong format.

---

I've tried setting the cell format to numeric

```
row.getCell(4).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

but this causes the 10-digit strings to show up as numbers between 11 and 165.
i.e. 11, 16, 20, 26, 13, 31, 35

---

I've also tried parsing the phone number into a long

```
try {
    row.createCell(4).setCellValue(Long.parseLong(c.getPhoneNumber()));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    row.createCell(4);
}
```

There is no setCellValue(Long) only setCellValue(Double), so I would assume that Strings are the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CELL_TYPE_STRING](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#CELL_TYPE_STRING) in your case and directly set the value of your phone number like this

```
row.createCell(4).setCellValue(c.getPhoneNumber()); // since getPhoneNumber returns a String
```

The [HSSFCell#setCellType](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#setCellType%28int%29) takes in an `int` value and `CELL_TYPE_STRING` or `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` are all static int fields provided by POI itself to set the cell type appropriately.

Comment: This is how I would assume it works. But when I open the excel file I get 4.165551234E9

Comment: Even after specifying the cell type as `String` and setting a String a string to it?! Did you try to print your String before setting to see if its in the proper format?

Comment: Yep, I messed up on that one. I'm extracting from an excel file where it's stored as a numeric value, gotta fix that up.

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt is correct:

```
row.createCell(4).setCellValue(c.getPhoneNumber());
```

The input was in an incorrect format, to get a String phoneNumber from a numeric type Cell use:

```
String phone = ((long) r.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()) + "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI is behaving just the same as Excel does. If you put a really long number into Excel, in a default formatted cell, it will store the number as-is, but display it in scientific format.

What you need to do, which is the same as what you'd do in Excel, is to set the formatting rules on the cell to tell Excel to display lots of numbers.

For example, if I want a UK phone number to display properly, then I need to ask Excel to format the cell with the following format string:

```
0###########
```

Or if I wanted the normal spacing:

```
0##### ### ###
```

Assuming the latter, what I'd do is:

```
// Do this only once per style
DataFormat df = workbook.createDataFormat()

CellStyle phoneStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
phoneStyle.setDataFormat( df.getFormat("0##### ### ###") );

....

// Create a cell, set the number, and apply our phone formatting to it
cell.setCellValue(phoneNumber);
cell.setCellStyle(phoneStyle);
```

Alternately, you can store the number as a string, but excel tends to sulk about that and complain you have a number stored as a string and give warnings about that. However, it does give you the chance to have complete control over the spaces, layout etc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when getting the value of a cell.  I just changed the cell type in my program to a cell type string, and then it was fine.

Comment: As is [very clearly explained in the JavaDocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29), setting the cell type is *never* the right way to get a string of the cell's contents! You need to use [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) + cell format rules for that